# Tailing a remote file in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

is it possible in Windows, with command line (cmd or Powershell) to tail a remote file that is accessible via FTP with user/password credentials?

Comment: Yes...Write some code and post back with a question about the code itself not working.

Comment: This github code purports to do what you want. I have not used it and I do not know if it is suitable for Windows. Requires Perl. https://github.com/johntdyer/ftptail/blob/master/ftptail